# Represent xs:choice as JSON schema

Tags: json, xml, xsd, jsonschema

Wrapping my head around JSON Schema's `oneOf`.

I want to produce a JSON version of an XML format and have a JSON schema validate the essential aspects (I know there'll be some differences).

I have an XML Schema concept where you can specify a name or ID for some entity:

```
<xs:element name="Entity" type="test:EntityType" />
    <xs:complexType name="EntityType">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="EntityID" />
            <xs:element name="EntityName" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
```

In the corresponding JSON schema I'm having trouble with *where to put the `oneOf` object*.

In [the JSON schema examples](http://json-schema.org/example2.html) it looks like you should put complete schemas into `oneOf`, is that right? How should this look in the general case? Has anyone documented the similarities and differences between XSD and JSON schema for reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't try it myself, but I think you need something like this:

```
{
    "allOf" : [
        {
            "type" : "object",
            "properties" : {
                "entityName" : {"type" : "string"},
                "entityID" : {"type" : "integer"}
            }
        },
        {
            "oneOf" : [
                {
                    "required" : ["entityName"]
                },
                {
                    "required" : ["entityID"]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So after under a top-level `"allOf"` you first describe the basic structure, then with a `"oneOf"` you express the choice.

Comment: OK, that's pretty mind-blowing stuff. So the available cardinalities are hidden inside a forking logic. Nice. Let me try that and I'll come back with a rating.

Comment: Thanks @erosb - for an untested answer this worked really well!

Comment: Excellent and not-so-obvious solution! Nice trick.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the issue you are facing is a small impedance mismatch between the XML and JSON data models.

While both are based on trees, the labels of the XML elements or JSON keys are not placed on the same places in the trees: from a logical perspective, XML element names are placed on the **nodes** of the tree, while JSON keys are placed on the **edges** of the tree.

This becomes apparant in XML Schema and in JSON Schema, especially with your example. XML schema, with `xs:choice`, provides a choice between possible elements (nodes in the XML information set data model), and since these elements carry their names with them (labels on nodes), you get to choose these element names as well together with their layouts.

However, in JSON Schema, the `oneOf` construct allows to pick an object layout, but this does *not* include picking a name (labels on edges). In other words, the key (EntityID or EntityName) is specified **outside** of the `oneOf` construct. This means that the mapping of `xs:choice` to `oneOf` is not as straightforward as it seems and it requires finding less obvious workarounds.